# How to start eclipse while in gnome shell?

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher, eclipse

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 10.04 to 11.10 using a USB stick. On 10.04 I had a manual Eclipse installation, that got correctly integrated into the Unity launch bar (meaning that I can start and run it).

But when I log into Gnome Shell it is like Eclipse was never there. I can search for it all I want, its just never found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a script in `~/bin` called `eclipse`, make it executable by running

```
chmod + x ~/bin/eclipse
```

Edit the file to look like

```
#!/bin/sh

export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
```

Just make sure that the path in the last line points the eclipse executable in your Eclipse installation. Now every time you run `eclipse`, this script will be called, which in turn will run Eclipse.

You can also put the script in `/usr/bin` if you want to make it available to all users.